# Разделить данные из select

Tags: html

Есть множественный `select` с группами:

```html
<select name="place[]" multiple>
  <optgroup label="Станции метро">
 <option value="metro1">Cтанция 1</option>
 <option value="metro2">Cтанция 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Районы">
 <option value="district1">Район 1</option>
 <option value="district1">Район 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

При передаче в обработчик, получаем подобный массив:

```
"place":["metro1","metro2","raion1"]
```

Вопрос: как, если, конечно, возможно, разбить передаваемые данные на вложенные массивы?
Чтобы получилось вроде:

```
"place":{"metro":["metro1", "metro2"],"district":["district1"]}
```

Если невозможно, то какие способы есть для разделения подобных данных (на ум приходят только префиксы для `value`)?

Comment: а серверная часть на чем написана

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если прям так сильно нужно, можно попробовать сделать так, не самый оптимальный вариант конечно:

В примере используется **[Jquery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js)**

> HTML

```
<form action="test.php" method="GET">
    <select name="place[]" id="placeID" multiple>
      <optgroup data-name="metro" label="Станции метро">
        <option value="metro1">Cтанция 1</option>
        <option value="metro2">Cтанция 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-name="district" label="Районы">
        <option value="district1">Район 1</option>
        <option value="district1">Район 2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="select_array" id="select_array">
<input type="submit" value="Вывод">
</form>
```

> Jquery

```
$('#placeID').change(function() {  
    var arr = {};  
    $('select :selected').each(function(){

    $('optgroup ').each(function() {
        arr[$(this).data('name')] = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
             return $(this).val();
        }).get();
    });
    console.log( JSON.stringify(arr) ); //Вывод для понимания
    $("#select_array").val( JSON.stringify(arr) );
});
```

> php

```
<?php 
  print_r($_GET['select_array']);

  print_r(json_decode( $_GET['select_array'] ,true)); //parse
?>
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, возьму на вооружение. Но думал, что я просто не знаю всех возможностей `html` форм. И `optgroup` имеет хоть какой-то смысл в этом плане. 
Спасибо и на этом. 
Буду делать выбор между таким костылём и костылём с префиксами